# AngularJS Input Value Don't Update When Erasing The Text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names" multiple>
     </select>
     <input value="{{selectedName[0]}}">
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

As you can see I have a select that should update the input value when clicking on an option, and it works, but when I erase some text from the input and click on an option it won't update the input value anymore.

**Note**: when i check the html in the inspector the value attribute is updated but not visually in the input element

Is there any explanation or solution to this?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to not use $scope object in your project but just to quick resolve your issue. There is plenty way to achieve it for example you can use ng-change directive. Instead of value attribute use ng-model directive. As I see select has multiply attribute use join() inside ng-change fn to change array to a string with multiply values.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-change="update(selectedName)" ng-model="selectedName"
          ng-options="x for x in names" multiple>
  </select>
  <input ng-model="selected">
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    $scope.update = function(value) {
        $scope.selected = value.join();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use same `ng-model` on the input element to maintain bidirectional communication between the `select` and `input` elements.

However since you use `multiple` directive on the `select` element, the selected model value is saved as an array, while the value entered manually in the input is saved as a string.

You can overcome this issue by adding a directive to the input element that parses the model value to an array, here is the example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names" multiple></select>
   <input ng-model="selectedName" to-array>
</div>
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});

app.directive('toArray', function(){
  return{
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      function toArray(viewValue){       
        return viewValue && viewValue.split(',');
      }
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(toArray);
    }
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: What if we want one way binding only?

Comment: I think the answer from @panatoni covers one-way binding approach

Answer (score 0):

probably you are trying to select the same range of items starting from THE SAME value. In your example you try to show exclusively first selected item.

change:

```
<input value="{{selectedName[0]}}">
```

into:

```
<input value="{{selectedName}}">
```

seems to be working fine. For this example I would recommend using: ui-select